# In odoo how can I match content of the email body to the description field in leads

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

In auto lead through incoming email I have added the code shown below that how to add body of email into description but I am getting as html format
Can anybody know how to add content of the email body same as into description field.

```py
def message_new(self, cr, uid, msg, custom_values=None, context=None):

    myString = msg.get('subject', '')
    myString.index('Phone:')
    mobileNumber =  myString[myString.index('Phone:')+6:myString.index('Phone:')+16]

    if context is None:
        context = {}
    data = {}
    if isinstance(custom_values, dict):
        data = custom_values.copy()
    model = context.get('thread_model') or self._name
    model_pool = self.pool[model]
    fields = model_pool.fields_get(cr, uid, context=context)

    if 'name' in fields and not data.get('name'):
        data['name'] = msg.get('subject', '')
    if 'mobile' in fields and not data.get('mobile'):
        data['mobile'] = mobileNumber
    if 'description' in fields and not data.get('description'):
        data['description'] = msg.get('body', '')

    res_id = model_pool.create(cr, uid, data, context=context)
    return res_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out:

```py
from openerp.tools import html2plaintext
# ...
if 'description' in fields and not data.get('description'):
    data['description'] = html2plaintext(msg.get('body')) if msg.get('body') else ''
# ...
```

Comment: Thank u it is working.But one more question.Can you help me If have content in mail body as Customer name:abcd,City:Bangalore phone:1234567890.So i need that these details i want to fill in fields that are present in leads y incoming email.How can I o it.

Comment: if the emails are formatted the same way everytime you can just search the body for typical phrases like "name:". But i think that emails aren't formatted the same every time so, no i don't know how to do that. Just ask this as a new question on stackoverflow with some email examples.

Comment: Yes I will recieve a same email template every time this the format.Caller Name: abcd
Caller Requirement:xyz
Call Date & Time: Wed, 08 Jun 2016 15:49:14
Branch Info: Anna Nagar
City: Chennai
Caller Phone: +918951452361
Caller Email: abcd@gmail.com for this I have written the code as myString2 = html2plaintext(msg.get('body', ''))
  myString2.index('City:')
  city = myString2[myString2.index('City:')+5:myString2.index('City:')+20] if 'city' in fields and not data.get('city'):
   data['city'] = city and it is working but the problem is index of string is continuing next line in feild

Comment: that's a typical question for python developers. i recommend to ask a complete new question, with this task. i bet there are some interesting pythonic ways to solve that. :-)